# How to give another user full access to my videos using vimeo API

Tags: vimeo-api

I have two different vimeo PRO users. And I created an app using one user to use the vimeo API. I can access all of the this user's videos using the developer API, I can even access the download links of HD files etc.

But I cannot access the download links/HD files of videos uploaded to this second vimeo account. Is there a way I can allow the first user's developer account full access to both vimeo users videos ?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions of your API call are defined by your access token. If you make requests using an access token created for the second account, that access token will be able to access the second users videos.

Comment: I want to be able to access videos under both user accounts using a single access token. Is that a possibility ?

Comment: No it is not possible. The only way to access direct video links is to have an access token authenticated as the owner of that video.